# mysql 8.0.15 not working in wamp 3.1.0

Tags: apache-http-server, php, mysql, wamp

I am using wamp 3.1.0 version with this i get version mysql 5.7.19.This is working fine but when i upgrade mysql verion to 8.0.15 from http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en&prerequis=afficher#mysql_versions this site
now i have 2 versions of mysql are currently available 
[mysql versions on wamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3C3n.png)

I restarted wamp but still mysql service is not working

in mysql console it shows error `[ERROR] [MY-000077] [Server] c:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.15\bin\mysqld.exe: Error while setting value 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' to 'sql_mode'.`

Comment: Are you sure the version of MySQL you are using is `8.1.15`?  I can find no reference to that version on the MySQL website.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by the `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` flag.

To fix it, do this:

1. Edit `c:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.15\my.ini`
2. Search for `sql-mode` and remove the `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` flag from the list

Mine looks like this:

```
sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE"
```

Start your MySQL service and enjoy.